# Android scan wifi signal while keep wifi connection alive

Tags: android, connection, wifi

I met an issue when I need to collect the wifi ssid around my android device and then submit these information through wifi connection using http post. But then I found that when I try to scan the wifi signal (interval is 1 min), the wifi connection would break sometimes. This will make my device could not submit data sometimes.

Is there any method to make it possible just scan and not breaking the connection?

Thanks

Comment: Scaning will not break the current wifi connection. Open a terminal emulator, ping a reachable ip, then scan wifi at 'wifi setting' again and again. you will find ping always reach the target ip.

Comment: Actually I think scanning will affect the result. When we are scanning, there might be a case that the scan results do not contain the ssid we are connecting to right now, then the device will think this network is not reachable at the moment. So I would like to know if there's a way that I could scan, but just let the device ignore what the results are.

Comment: you can reconnect to wifi if the disconnection detected.` reconnect()
Reconnect to the currently active access point, if we are currently disconnected. `